# Running a custom node module in scripts from packege.json

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I have build a node module that works, module name my-module.
When I install this module to a bigger project I want to run it in the packege.json.

This works like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "myModule" : "node ./node_modules/my-module"
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the reference to node_modules?
Having the scripts like the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "myModule" : "my-module"
}
```

Thank you all for the help
Moshe S.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your "my-module" package.json a "bin" field:

```
"bin": {
  "my-script": "./path-to-your-executable/my-module-script.js",
  "other-script": "./index.js"
}
```

And in your bigger project you can do

```
"scripts": {
   "start-my-module": "my-script", //Will look for "my-script" at ./node_modules/.bin/
   "start": "other-script"
}
```

And you can call your scripts from console in the regular way:

`npm run start`

This will execute index.js from "my-module".